# int object is not callable error in pyTenable docs?

Tags: python, python-3.x, object, integer

I am trying to pull vulnerability data from Tenable.SC, I am following the pyTenable docs but I am getting the "int object is not callable error". I have tried instantiating an integer first but there is still no use..

Here is my code as a minimum working example:

```
from tenable.sc import TenableSC
from pprint import pprint

sc = TenableSC('HOST')
sc.login('MYUSERNAME', 'MYPASSWORD')

vulns = sc.analysis.scan(1
                         ('severity', '=', '4'),
                         ('exploitAvailable', '=', 'true'))
pprint(vulns)
```

Why is python throwing this error when this code is taken directly from the docs here?
https://pytenable.readthedocs.io/en/stable/sc.html#analysis

Traceback:

```
File "C:XXXX.py", 
line 13, in <module> ('severity', '=', '4'), TypeError: 'int' object is not callable 

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: Can you show your error traceback?

Comment: @nobleknight Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:XXXX.py", line 13, in <module>
    ('severity', '=', '4'),
TypeError: 'int' object is not callable

Process finished with exit code 1

Comment: It looks like there is error in implementation of that module. I don't know much about it. Consider adding this traceback in your, it may help others to answer your question.